# Sorting results in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am beginner in Laravel.
I have project in Laravel 5.8.

I have this code:

```
Schema::create('user_profile_images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('path1', 255);
            $table->smallInteger('number1')->default(0);
            $table->string('path2', 255);
            $table->smallInteger('number2')->default(0);
            $table->string('path3', 255);
            $table->smallInteger('number3')->default(0);
            $table->string('path4', 255);
            $table->smallInteger('number4')->default(0);
            $table->string('path5', 255);
            $table->smallInteger('number5')->default(0);
            $table->string('path6', 255);
            $table->smallInteger('number6')->default(0);
            $table->string('path7', 255);
            $table->smallInteger('number7')->default(0);
            $table->ipAddress('ip');
            $table->engine = "InnoDB";
            $table->charset = 'utf8mb4';
            $table->collation = 'utf8mb4_unicode_ci';
        });
```

User.php

```
public function UserProfileImageGallery()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\UserProfileImage', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

I need to display the user's path (path1, path2, path3, path4 ... path7) in order of number (number1, number2, number3 ... number7).

for example:

```
$path1 = "www1";
$number1 = 2;
$path2 = "www2";
$number2 = 1;
$path3 = "www3";
$number3 = 3;
```

In result I need:

www2, www1, www3

How can I make it?

Comment: You are creating columns on a table, but my guess is that you want to order results / records / rows. Migrations are not queries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user_profile_images table:

```
Schema::create('user_profile_images', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('user_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_id')->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->ipAddress('ip');

        });
```

user_profile_images_pathes table:

```
Schema::create('user_profile_images_pathes', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->bigIncrements('id');
            $table->bigInteger('user_profile_images_id')->unsigned();
            $table->foreign('user_profile_images_id')->references('id')->on('user_profile_images')->onDelete('cascade');
            $table->string('path', 255);
            $table->smallInteger('number')->default(0);

        });
```

User.php

```
public function UserProfileImageGallery()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\UserProfileImage', 'user_id', 'id');
    }
```

user_profile_images.php

```
 public function UserPathes()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\user_profile_images_pathes', 'user_profile_images_id', 'id')->orderBy('number');
    }
```

in your controller

```
$user=User::find(1);
$user->UserProfileImageGallery->UserPathes;
```

Comment: and what's now? @foreach($user->UserProfileImageGallery as $photo)
                                {{ $photo->....... }}<br/>
                            @endforeach ? I need path ordered by number... :)

Comment: @choujam
if you really need to number_1 to number_7 and path_1 to 7

create another table path has include columns(path and number and user_profile_images_id) then order by number